# how do I create a SpatialpolygonsDataFrame from a SpatialLinesDataFrame

Tags: r-sf, rgdal

I am trying to create a mask for a project using the packages sf and RGDAL. I have a shapefile which is a SpatiallinesDataFrame and it needs to be a SpatialpolygonsDataFrame to continue.

I have tried these codes

```
    fence1 <- as(fence1 ,"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
    fence1 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(fence1)
    fence1 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(fence1, match.ID = TRUE)
```

The fence1 is the SpatiallinesDataFrame that i imported from a shp. file using the code:

```
    fence1 <- readOGR('/SECR/', layer = 'building')
```

The aim of this data is to create a mask so i can create a SECR analysis

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `sf`, you could read in using:

```
fence1 <- st_read('/SECR/building.shp')
```

You could then do a buffer to make these lines polygons, choosing width in units of your projection:

```
fence_buf <- st_buffer(fence1, 50) # buffer unit of 50 as example
```

Then if you need your polygons as an `sp` SpatialPolygonsDataFrame you could convert from `sf` to `sp`:

```
fence_buf <- as(fence_buf, 'Spatial')
```